# Await a promise within another function

Tags: node.js, async-await

I am trying to implement the following pseudo code in a nodejs app --

```
async task1(){
  await asyncFunc();
  return true;
}

let task1IsDone = await task1();

if(task1IsDone){
  task2();
}
```

But from all the documentation I have read on async/await it seems like the normal way of using async await is like --

```
let data;
  data = await task1();
task2(data);
```

Is there a way to use async await in the manner I am trying to in my psuedo code? 
Is there any reason to not try to do it that way (simple Boolean being returned)?

**Real code** --

```
  getList: async function(type,startDate){
    request(BASE_URL+'data.json?tz=America/Vancouver&ftime=DeviceEntryDate&stime='+startDate+'&fids='+type, async (error, response, body) => {    
      console.log('error:', error);
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
        await fs.writeFile('downloads/'+type+'.json',body, (err) =>{
          if(err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
          console.log('5');
        });
        console.log('7');
        return true;              
    });
  }
```

or

```
  getList: async function(type,startDate){
    await  request(BASE_URL+'data.json?tz=America/Vancouver&ftime=DeviceEntryDate&stime='+startDate+'&fids='+type, (error, response, body) => {    
      console.log('error:', error);
      console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
        fs.writeFile('downloads/'+type+'.json',body, (err) =>{
          if(err) {
              console.log(err);
          }
          console.log('5');
        });
        console.log('7');

    });
    return true; 
  }
```

Comment: Is this not working?

Comment: Nope, task1 returns true before the asyncFunc completes

Comment: Can we see ```asyncFunc```?

Comment: added real code

Comment: Or at least you need to return a promise...

Comment: You are mixing callback with promises & async/await

Comment: Yep just picking up async await. i have added  where I am doing that. Sorry about that

Comment: request is an async function. You need to check if it can return a promise, if so, you need to await request instead of sending a callback. If it doesnt, you need to convert it to a promise, and await the promise

Comment: I am using request-promise-native which makes request return a promise. And I have tried awaiting on that but it still didn't work. Added second version of code

Comment: That form of ```request()``` doesn't look right.  You're still using the request callback notation.  For promises, you would chain ```.then()``` or assign the result to your ```await```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your request returns a promise, this would be what it looks like:

```
getList: async function(type,startDate){
  try {
    const response = await request(BASE_URL+'data.json?tz=America/Vancouver&ftime=DeviceEntryDate&stime='+startDate+'&fids='+type);
    console.log('statusCode:', response.statusCode); 
    await fsPromises.writeFile('downloads/'+type+'.json',body);
    console.log('5');
    return true
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error:', error);
    return false; //false if error?
  }
}
```

Also note that fs doesn't return a promise, so you need to use the experimental [fsPromises](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api)

Comment: Thanks. I can see what I was doing wrong. Trying to use async await while still keeping the structure from callbacks.